# Lucee cfexecute non blocking mode

Tags: cfml, lucee

I have a long running process that I just need to run the shell script

```
<cfset luceeUpdate = "/usr/share/lucee_update">
<cfset args = [ "-D", "lucce.org"] />
<cfexecute name="#luceeUpdate#" variable="result" arguments="#args#"  errorvariable="errorV" timeout="0" </cfexecute>
```

I tried using timeout=0 so that the cfexecute will run in a non blocking mode but cfexecute still runs in a blocking mode

OS: Ubuntu VERSION=“18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)” Linux (4.15.0) 64bit

Java Version: 11.0.6 (AdoptOpenJDK) 64bit

Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.34

Lucee Version: Lucee 5.3.6.61

I can see the chrome spinning indicator that its running and Apache throws Proxy error after a few minutes.

How do you know it is running in blocking mode when you set the timeout to 0?
The shell script runs for 30 mins. I called the cfm page in Chrome I can see spinning indicator that its running and Apache throws Proxy error after a few minutes. The cfm page doesn't do anything except running the code above. The process should have loaded immediately and closed the request but its keeping the request open and processing.

How can I make the timeout=0 in a non blocking mode? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How do you know it is running in blocking mode when you set the timeout to 0? What are you seeing when that code runs?  Any errors?  Any logs?  Any output?

Comment: its a long running process. I can see the chrome spinning indicator that its running and Apache throws Proxy error after a few minutes.

Comment: So is the issue that your task is timing out before it completes or that control is not returning to the page? Please share the error details.